# cgroups in CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

Tags: centos7, cgroups

I have virtual machine "CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)" , where I can not find cgroups, "/sys/fs/cgroup" directory has nothing in it. I have also installed cgrouplib pakages but still there is nothing.

How I can get cgroups , would be very helpful you anyone can provide the details.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: cgrouplib packages are deprecated on centos7.  they supposedly still work, but deprecated means they'll probably stop working randomly one day.  for me, that day has passed ;P

Answer (score 0):

Centos has cgroups installed under /cgroup.

You can check the enabled cgroups under `/proc/cgroups`.

`cat /proc/mounts | grep ^cgroup` will give the location where cgroups are mounted.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for reply, but I am running centos 7 and there is no cgroup , when i run "cat /proc/mounts | grep ^cgroup" , it returns nothing, is there a way we can configure this manually?

Comment: These instructions are pretty generic and might work for you:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-Creating_a_Hierarchy_and_Attaching_Subsystems.html